# Python Flask Windows export all the environment variables from the .env file?

Tags: python, windows, flask

I am fully aware on Linux I can use the command: `source .env`
So I made a env.bat and executed it.
My env.bat file:

```
set export SECRET_KEY=fdkjshfhjsdfdskfdsfdcbsjdkfdsdf
set export DEBUG=True
set export APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
set export DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite
set export FLASK_APP=src
set export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

now receiving this error:

```
python manage.py run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src import app
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\src\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.config.from_object(config("APP_SETTINGS"))
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 248, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 107, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 92, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: APP_SETTINGS not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows, replace export with set:

```
set SECRET_KEY=fdkjshfhjsdfdskfdsfdcbsjdkfdsdf
set DEBUG=True
set APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
set DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite
set FLASK_APP=src
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

and save it in a `env.bat` file.

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm seeming to getting another error, i'll update the post with it.